# Macbook A1342 2010 - OS Installation Issue

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I purchased a Macbook A1342 2010 (white one) from eBay and it arrived with software and a password on it. This was not in the seller's description. I instinctively (have had many macs before) used Disc Utility to wipe the disk and reinstall OS. All was going well until when I went to sign in before installation began it said: "This item is temporarily unavailable". I went on the internet in search of answers and someone suggested to use Online Recovery (which I did) and it reverted back to OSx Lion. The exact same error happened with Lion as it did with El Capitan right before it begins installing - "This item is temporarily unavailable". The Apple ID that I used has been used with Macs before but no older than El Capitan. I tried two Apple IDs which have both been used on Macs and both were refused. The seller is saying it is my fault despite him being the one that sold a locked product without stating so and eBay have ruled in his favour. How can I go about fixing this mess?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to any other Macs? If so, what operating systems are they running?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the installer have you tried creating the bootable thumb drive from [here](https://www.maciverse.com/install-os-x-lion-from-a-usb-drive.html)?

Reading closer you don't have access to the installer.  Running the online installer won't work because apple pulled the download links that it uses.  I suspect this is thinly veiled attempt at pushing people to upgrade.

Check this out:  https://diskmakerx.com. It will create the thumb drive for you.  You will most likely have to go [here](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12) and buy El Capitan from apple if you haven't installed already.

Its also worth checking out http://dosdude1.com/highsierra/ his tool will download the High Sierra installer for you from apple.  This is the last supported release for your MacBook.  Once you have the installer you can use DiskMakerX.